# Firebase push notifications with node.js and flutter

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating the push notifications functionality with firebase using node.js backend and flutter for front-end.

Till now I have learned about push notifications, register the application with firebase, and then successfully tested the notifications with the firebase console.

But I am having the confusion that how to handle the FCM token. as the firebase will send a notification to specific devices using the FCM token how can I get the FCM token from the front-end??

The solution that I have figured out is that when the user logged in to the mobile app the FCM token will be generated and will be sent to the node server from there I will store that FCM token in the database. So sending notifications will be easy to handle

is it a good approach?

or there is any good approach for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is indeed the correct approach, and is described in the Firebase documentation on [accessing the registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) (this link is for Java, but the same exists on all supported platforms). From there comes this code sample:

```
/**
 * There are two scenarios when onNewToken is called:
 * 1) When a new token is generated on initial app startup
 * 2) Whenever an existing token is changed
 * Under #2, there are three scenarios when the existing token is changed:
 * A) App is restored to a new device
 * B) User uninstalls/reinstalls the app
 * C) User clears app data
 */
@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // FCM registration token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(token);
}
```

The `onNewToken` here is part of the FCM API, but the `sendRegistrationToServer` in this code is what you are describing and something you will have to implement yourself.